# issues on redux toolkit EntitiyAdapter

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I created a website and use redux-toolkit
but I have an issue with createSlice. my two records data receive correctly. but when I set data into adapter just the first record was added. this is my slice code

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSlice, PayloadAction, createSelector, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fetchTop10Podcasts } from "../../../services/endpoints/Podcasts";
import { podcastState } from "../../initialStates/Podcasts";
const podcastAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

// interface podcastState {
//     entities: Array<Podcast>
//     loading: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'successed' | 'failed'
// }


export const PodcastSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'podcasts',
    initialState: podcastAdapter.getInitialState({
        entities: [],
        loading: 'idle'
    } as podcastState),
    reducers: {
    }, extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchTop10Podcasts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = 'loading';
        }).addCase(fetchTop10Podcasts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = 'successed';
            podcastAdapter.setAll(state, action.payload.data.podcasts)

            console.log('podcasts', action.payload.data.podcasts); // here I recieved two record

        }).addCase(fetchTop10Podcasts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = 'failed';
        })
    }
});

export const {
    selectById: selectPodcastById,
    selectAll: selectPodcasts
} = podcastAdapter.getSelectors((state: any) => state.podcasts)


export const selectPodcastIds = createSelector(
    selectPodcasts,
    podcasts => podcasts.map((podcast: any) => podcast._id)
)

export default PodcastSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What did you get? Show the debugging details

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue *may* be with your initial state.

When you call `adapter.getInitialState()`, the state structure it returns is `{ids: [], entities: {}}`, plus whatever additional fields you passed in.

You're providing `entities: []` as an additional field. It's likely you're overwriting the original object structure as a result.

Remove that line and I think this will work.

Comment: hey dear Mark . I fixed my issue by declare my adapter like this code  =>  const podcastAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Podcast>({
    selectId: (podcast) => podcast._id
});